# Posting values in multiple forms separately with single function

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a task with a form that requests posting values in multiple forms separately by getting field values, all with single event function applied at each form submit call, so there could be multiple forms on page with same identifiers.
Please review this working example that handles only values of first field and suggest something in generic javascript if possible.

```
<script>
    function Order() {
        var formi=document.getElementById("test").value;
        document.getElementById("result").value=document.getElementById("test").value;
        alert(formi);
    }
</script>

<form onsubmit="Order();return false;">
<input type="text" id="test" value="">
<input type="text" id="result" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Order">
</form>

<form onsubmit="Order();return false;">
<input type="text" id="test" value="">
<input type="text" id="result" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Order">
</form>
```

Comment: You can't have 2 elements with the same `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="order(this); return false;">
<input type="text" class="test" value="foo">
<input type="text" class="result" value="bar">
<input type="submit" value="Order">
</form>

<form method="post" onsubmit="order(this); return false;">
<input type="text" class="test" value="abc">
<input type="text" class="result" value="def">
<input type="submit" value="Order">
</form>

<script>
var order = function (form) {
    var fields = form.querySelectorAll('input');
    alert(fields[0].value + ', ' + fields[1].value);
}
</script>
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/KyHMf/

Comment: Thank you it is working, how could I pass now fields value as string into new variable?

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use the same id multiple times as it is not allowed in html and will not work as you intended.

Here is the improved version of your code:

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');

function FormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = e.target.children[0].value;
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
        forms[i].children[1].value = text;
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].onsubmit = FormSubmit;
}
```

You can try it here, the code has some extra comments for clarity.

http://jsfiddle.net/Hq8uz/1/

Comment: well I know about it, but the forms are on auto generated page and I have to post process ordering data, thanks for your informations